# Elasticsearch takes in minute for respond to aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

```
Document count: 4 Billion
disc size : 2 TB
Primary: 5 
replica: 2
master node : 3
data node: 4 * [16cpu and 64GB ram]
heap size: 30GB
mlock enable : true
```

It takes up to 3 minutes to respond to aggregation queries. On subsequent request, it caches and speeds things up. Is there a way to speed the aggregation on the first query?

Example aggregation query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg_;COUNT_ROWS;5d8b0621690e727ff775d4ed": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "feild1.keyword",
        "size": 10000,
        "shard_size": 100,
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_;COUNT_ROWS;5d8b0621690e727ff775d4ec": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "feild2.keyword",
            "size": 30,
            "shard_size": 100,
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_HouseHold;COUNT_DISTINCT": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "feild3.keyword",
                "precision_threshold": 40000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're retrieving up to 300K buckets, that's a huge amount of data to process... Can you explain your use case and why exactly you need to do it that way?

Comment: I am building kibana dashboard for display charts and maps. user can create any aggregations charts.@Val

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you are running the query on a single instance, with a total of 15 shards, 5 of which are primaries. The first `terms` aggregation have a size of 10,000. that is a high number that effects performance. consider moving to [composite-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) in order to use pagination and not to try to squeeze it to a huge response.

Also, the `shard_size` doesn't make much sense to me, as you only query 5 shards, and asking for 10,000 results - bringing 100 results from 5 shards would yield 500 results, which is not enough. I would drop this `shard_size` param, or set a higher value in order for it to make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, Kibana doesn't (yet) support composite aggs

Comment: I didn't know it is running from Kibana. @BlackPOP I agree with val, you need to decrease the size in order to increase performance

Comment: I am running on 3 masters 4 data node cluster

Comment: what I meant is that you are using a single index, with 5 shards. this means that the query gets run on 5 shards, and returning 300K docs - this is indeed a huge response and not an efficient one. Why do you really need the 10K size on the first agg? you better return smaller result set, and use filters in order to drill down to the interesting docs, instead of letting humans look at >100K results in kibana